# mysql query return null row

Tags: mysql

i want to execute this query but it return null row when the table  empty. it's working when `SUM(products.sale_price)/COUNT(orders.id) AS avg_price_rang`
  is not in the query

```
SELECT
    products.brand_id,
    (SELECT
        category_brands.name
     FROM
        category_brands
     WHERE
        category_brands.id=products.brand_id
    ) AS brand,
    products.material_id,
    (SELECT
        category_materials.material
     FROM
        category_materials
     WHERE
        category_materials.id=products.material_id
    ) AS material,
    orders.color_code,
    SUM(products.sale_price)/COUNT(orders.id) AS avg_price_rang
FROM
    orders
INNER JOIN
    products
ON
    orders.prodcut_id = products.id
```

Comment: If the table is empty, what do you expect it to return for the sum?

Comment: ^^ Agreed ...  It's going to return the `SUM` of something .. Even if that "something" is "nothing" ..

Comment: Did you forget to include `GROUP BY`?

Comment: When the query uses an aggregate function like `SUM` or `COUNT`, and there's no `GROUP BY` option, it always returns exactly one row, which combines all the rows selected.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "null row"? When what table is empty? (There are 4 base tables here plus the subselects.) Please show DDL, input, output and the actual query you ran. (Is `orders.prodcut_id` [sic] a typo?) Read about an MCVE in the help page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's missing `GROUP BY products.brand_id`.

Answer (score 1):

SELECTing SUM when there are no rows causess a row of all NULLs to be returned.

[MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual

12.17.1 GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html)

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows. For more information, see Section 12.17.3, “MySQL Handling of GROUP BY”.

Use:

```
query
HAVING avg_price_rang IS NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM (
    query
    ) dummy
WHERE avg_price_rang IS NOT NULL
```